# PHP - check if a value not existing in the csv file with database

Tags: php, database, csv, delete-row

I need help, I gave trying to make this works but I can't.

I have a CSV file that get auto updated, I need to check if data on csv was deleted.

If yes, I need to delete this data also in the database.

For this i have put the csv code (to see if it much to the database value) inside of the while database loop.

I don't know if this is the solution, but I hope you can help to find a solution for me.

Here is the full code:

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);        

$select_all_sku = "
  SELECT
      wp_postmeta.*, wp_posts.*
  FROM u779870322_y7MxR.wp_posts
  INNER JOIN u779870322_y7MxR.wp_postmeta 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
  WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='_fragrancex_item'";   
    
$read_all_sku = $conn->query($select_all_sku);
        
while($all_sku = $read_all_sku->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mm = $all_sku["meta_value"];
    $file_handle = fopen("test.csv", "r") or die("can't open");
    $c = 1;
    
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    
        if($c>1) {
            if ($line_of_text[0] == $mm) {
                $OK = "ok";
            }
        }
        $c++;
    }
        
    fclose($file_handle);

    if(isset($OK)) {
    
        $delete_query ="DELETE
            wp_postmeta.*, wp_posts.*
        FROM u779870322_y7MxR.wp_posts
        INNER JOIN u779870322_y7MxR.wp_postmeta 
            ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
        WHERE 
            wp_postmeta.meta_key='_fragrancex_item' AND
            wp_postmeta.meta_value='$mm'";
     
      $conn->query($delete_query);
  } //if not found  
}//loop DB
        
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Please a little formatting of your code so it's readable

Comment: I don't understand, why is not readable?
what do you not understand?, my code is very clear.
you have the first section = select db, then you have search in csv file.

Comment: It was completely unreadable before Slava Rozhne formatted it.

Comment: first thank you Slava Rozhne for formatting the code, 
I copy past from DW, it's my second post and now I know what to do next time.
About my code someone have a solution? I have found a solution using sessions.
the session will collect the data individually next it will much 1 session to other session in the csv loop, this fixed my problem but not Shure if it's good idea.

Comment: Question 1: why do you need to read the entire csv for every row ? Why don't you just read it once, store the needed variable in an array, then loop over your rows and check against the array ? Question 2: it seems to me that once $ok=1; $ok will always be set

Comment: Hello, first about the $ok, you are correct I have notice it will be always true. 
second I don't know how to read the entire CSV, can you please show me how?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to how to read the entire csv and then loop**

You're already doing it. Just execute this before looping over the rows

```
$file_handle = fopen("test.csv", "r") or die("can't open");
$c = 1;
$values = []; // initialize an empty one dimension array
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    if($c++ > 1) $values[] = $line_of_text[0]; // fill the array
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

now you can loop over the rows and just check

```
if (in_array($mm, $values))
```

Comment: It's working, i have made some changes but your code do the work.
Thank you so much